# RTSP Media Server Using Netty

Tags: java, streaming, rtsp, multimedia, netty

After carrying out some research I have found out that an RTSP media server for develivering video and audio can be implemeneted in java using Netty. After consulting the web site and veiwing the documentation I have still not found any real help on how an RTSP media server can be implemeneted using it. I have been stucktrying to solve this problem for a while now and I am well aware of the RTSP protocol, other streaming protocols and all the issues that come with streaming media. Could someone please piont me at a place to start so that I can slowly work my way through the implemenattion of an RTSP server in java (Netty). Any online documentation or source code that is reasonably close to this issue, or shows the very basics would be a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [flazr](http://flazr.com/) which is Netty implementation for streaming protocols like RTMP. Another place where you might find relevant information is the related [projects page](http://www.jboss.org/netty/related-projects) of Netty.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve it is to create a new Netty project and make a HTTP server and client, then modify it into a RTSP server and client.